# while php ajax не работает

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Как реализовать вывод данных циклом на ajax?

```
function getTableKredit(){
        debugger;
            var id;
            $.ajax({
                url:"credit-table.php",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){                
                    //как виводить
                },
                error: function(data){

                }
            })
    }




$queryCredit = "SELECT * FROM `credit`";
$resCredit = mysqli_query($conection, $queryCredit);


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resCredit)) {

    $output = [
            "id" => $row['id'],
            "description" => $row['description'],
            "grn" => $row['grn'],
            "pln" => $row['pln'],
            "eur" => $row['eur'],
        ];

    echo json_encode($output);


}
```

Comment: Вы выводите неверный json (т.к. json_encode выводится больше 1 раза), функция "success" в js из-за этого не будет вызвана. Попробуйте разобраться в том, как работает php/js/json, будет понятней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас некорректный json получается. Сериализовать надо сразу все данные, а не частями. Накопите данные в цикле `while` и отправьте сразу все.

```
$output = [];
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resCredit)) {

    $output[] = [
            "id" => $row['id'],
            "description" => $row['description'],
            "grn" => $row['grn'],
            "pln" => $row['pln'],
            "eur" => $row['eur'],
        ];
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Потихоньку вылезаем из каменного века,

```
$queryCredit = "SELECT * FROM `credit`";
$output = $conection->query($queryCredit)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($output);
```